# Entity Framework - TPC - Override Primary Key Column Name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Here's my model:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Audit : Entity
{}

public class UserAudit : Audit
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{}
```

Here's my DbContext:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    static TestDbContext()
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AuditConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserAuditConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

And here's my mappings:

```
public abstract class EntityConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    protected EntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Key");
    }
}

public class AuditConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Audit>
{}

public class UserAuditConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserAudit>
{
    public UserAuditConfiguration()
    {
        Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("UserAudits");
            });
        HasRequired(u => u.User)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserKey"));
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<User>
{}
```

When I try to generate a migration for this model, I get the following error:

error 2010: The Column 'Id' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace.

If I comment out the ".HasColumnName" call in the constructor of EntityConfiguration, the migration generates correctly (except of course that the column name is Id and not Key).

Is TPC mappings supposed to support primary key columns that don't use the default column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that Entity Framework does not expect me to map Audit.  If I remove AuditConfiguration, this works as expected.